# Does close()ing InputStream release resoures even if it throws?

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream

Just a simple question.   Given this code:

```
try {
    // operation on inputstream "is"
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //if ioe is thrown, will the handle opened by 'is' be closed?
    }
}
```

If the `close()` throws, is the file handle still around (and leaked), or will it have been closed?

Comment: Depends on the stream, depends on the error.

Comment: If `close` on the underlying stream doesn't work, I don't suppose much will. (In practice `FileInputStream.close` will never throw.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not reliably so.  If `is.close()` throws, `is` might not be marked closed.  In any case, there is nothing you can do about it.  You don't know the internals of `is`.  The Java 7 equivalent simply hides the problem.

```
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(...)) {
    // Stuff with is.
} catch (IOException is) {
    ...  // Handles exceptions from the try block.
}  // No finally. Handled by try-with-reources
```

If the auto-close throws, the exception is a *suppressed exception*, and you'll never know if or when the file handle is reclaimed.